# Error accessing jQuery Autocomplete in Angular controller on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

In a div with Angular controller, there's an autocomplete that I'm trying to disable on document ready:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="myController">
  <!-- autocomplete -->
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#AutocompleteId').autocompletesearch('disable');
});
```

When I try to render the page, an error occurs:

> Error: cannot call methods on autocompletesearch prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'

It seems like the autocomplete initialization is not ended when I'm trying to access to it.

Comment: The error is because you've not created an `autocompletesearch` instance. In other words, there is nothing to disable yet.

Comment: after the page is loaded, if I wrote that instruction from the console I've not  that error anymore... what is wrong ?

Comment: In that case you're initialising the autocomplete *somewhere* in your code. The line above is being called *before* that has happened, hence the error.

Comment: maybe the content in the angular controller is rendered later ?